# Julia - Using readdlm gives bad @code_warntype performance

Tags: performance, file, types, julia, csv

The following code from [Julia's documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/#DelimitedFiles.readdlm-Tuple%7BAny,AbstractChar,Type,AbstractChar%7D) gives `@code_warntype` red performance (Union):

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> x = [1; 2; 3; 4];

julia> y = [5; 6; 7; 8];

julia> open("delim_file.txt", "w") do io
           writedlm(io, [x y])
       end

julia> readdlm("delim_file.txt", '\t', Int, '\n')
4×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5
 2  6
 3  7
 4  8



julia> @code_warntype readdlm("delim_file.txt", '\t', Int, '\n')
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(DelimitedFiles.readdlm, false)
  input::String
  dlm::Char
  T::Core.Compiler.Const(Int64, false)
  eol::Char

Body::Union{Tuple{Array{_A,2} where _A,Array{AbstractString,2}}, Array{_A,2} where _A}
1 ─ %1 = Core.NamedTuple()::Core.Compiler.Const(NamedTuple(), false)
│   %2 = Base.pairs(%1)::Core.Compiler.Const(Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}(), false)
│   %3 = DelimitedFiles.:(var"#readdlm#6")(%2, #self#, input, dlm, T, eol)::Union{Tuple{Array{_A,2} where _A,Array{AbstractString,2}}, Array{_A,2} where _A}
└──      return %3
```

I have a code using the same scheme and logically returning the same bad `code_warntype` performance. I could not find what to change to improve my code. Thank you for helping me!

```
function create_instance(filename)
    """
    This function creates instance from filename.
        Example of instance of 4 nodes in filename
        4
        1 0.5 0.5
        2 0 0
        3 1 1
        4 -2 4
    """
    data = readdlm(filename, ' ', Float64, '\n')
    n = Int(data[1,1])

    x_coors = data[2:n+1, 2]
    y_coors = data[2:n+1, 3]

    ring_costs = zeros(Float64, n, n)

    for i in 1:n
        for j in 1:n
            ring_costs[i,j] = dist([x_coors[i], y_coors[i]], [x_coors[j], y_coors[j]])
        end
    end
    return n, ring_costs
end

dist(x,y) = sqrt((x[1]-y[1])^2 + (x[2]-y[2])^2)
```

Comment: IO is generally type unstable/uncertain. Typically you want to isolate the type instability, i.e. the reading of the file, from performance sensitive code. Also you can use explicit type annotation to enforce conversion to `Matrix{Float64}` in the line `data = ...`. The compiler can than assume that data has that type.

Comment: @crstnbr, thank you a lot for your comment. Your second option suggests : `data = Matrix{Float64}(readdlm(filename, ' ', Float64, '\n'))`? That swaps the red `Union` with a red `Any`.

Comment: I meant suffixing the line with `::Matrix{Float64}`. But again, I would try to isolate (in different functions for example) the "data reading" part from the "computation". (see the answer by François Févotte)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is use a [function barrier](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#kernel-functions) in order to prevent the type instability from `readdlm` from propagating to the rest of your code.

Something like:

```
# The user-facing function
function create_instance(filename)
    """
    This function creates instance from filename.
        Example of instance of 4 nodes in filename
        4
        1 0.5 0.5
        2 0 0
        3 1 1
        4 -2 4
    """
    data = readdlm(filename, ' ', Float64, '\n')
    create_instance_(data)
end

# An inner function introducing a function barrier
# When this function is called, the concrete type of `data` will be known, and
# everything can be compiled efficiently.
function create_instance_(data)
    n = Int(data[1,1])

    x_coors = data[2:n+1, 2]
    y_coors = data[2:n+1, 3]

    ring_costs = zeros(Float64, n, n)

    for i in 1:n
        for j in 1:n
            ring_costs[i,j] = dist([x_coors[i], y_coors[i]], [x_coors[j], y_coors[j]])
        end
    end
    return n, ring_costs
end
```

Comment: Thank you!
Just a little detail, I see you use `create_instance_` with `_` at the end. I'm not aware of such a convention, could you explain briefly when I should do it please?

Comment: Another point, I see @code_warntype still returns red Union. I guess I have to ignore it now. But I found it not so easy to know when you have to ignore it and when you have to take attention, depending whether it's IO or another part of programming. Maybe it's with the habit and keeping asking here when I don't know?

Comment: I don't think there's a widespread convention of putting underscores at the end of function names. In this case, I just needed to give some name to this function, and I didn't want to think too long about it. In your own code, chances are that you can give a meaningful name to it. Or you could perhaps have two methods for the same function, like `create_instance(filename::AbstractString)` and `create_instance(data::AbstractArray)`

Comment: Yes `@code_warntype` still warns about instabilities, but you can notice that it now calls `create_instance_`. You could re-use `@code_warntype` to check that `create_instance_` is indeed type-stable. And you should be aware that `create_instance` itself still type-unstable: you'll have to take care of this in performance-sensitive contexts where it is called. For example, using function barriers in the same way as here in order to isolate the "computation part" from the type instability.